# Java -> MigLayout how to set gap's

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, miglayout

I have a small problem, i started a new GUI project using MigLayout and i love the layout but one thing i cannot figure out is how to remove all gaps between components them selves, components and frame and gap between cells and rows

Now MigLayout documentation describes using "gap 0px 0px" where gap [gapx] [gapy]
I did set gap to 0px on both axis but the gap is still there can someone help out here their forums are a ghost town : )

I want to remove the gap between JPanels and JFrame.. The red box and frame border, and
i want to remove the padding inside the red JPanel. My code is bellow:

[image]

```
package pe.view;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class UI_View extends JFrame
{
    //Content panels
    private JPanel  left   = new JPanel(new MigLayout());
    private JPanel  center = new JPanel(new MigLayout());
    private JPanel  right  = new JPanel(new MigLayout());

    //Content components
    private DefaultListModel list_content = new DefaultListModel();
    private JList   list   = new JList(list_content);

    public UI_View()
    {
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        this.setTitle("PropriarityEnvoirment");
        this.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        this.setLayout(new MigLayout("gap 0px 0px"));

        String data[] = {"Hi","Hello","WiWi","Hello","WiWi","Hello","WiWi","Hello","WiWi","Hello","WiWi","Hello","WiWi","Hello","WiWi","Hello","WiWi","Hello","WiWi"};
        for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        {
            list_content.addElement(data[i]);
        }

        left.add(list);

        left.setBackground(Color.red);
        center.setBackground(Color.green);
        right.setBackground(Color.blue);

        this.add(left, "growy, pushy");
        this.add(center, "grow, pushx");
        this.add(right, "grow, pushy");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remove the space between a container in miglayout you can make use of `Docking`, which is similar to BorderLayout.

With docking your code will look something like this:

```
...
this.setLayout(new MigLayout());
...
left.add(list, "dock north");
...
this.add(left, "dock west");
this.add(center, "dock center");
this.add(right, "dock east");
...
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: One follow up question on that at the part:   "left.add(list, "dock north")" i used to have it set to "left.add(list, "wrap, push")" and that bound the JList components to the borders so that means that the JList got re-sized whit the JFrame.

I have tried "left.add(list, "wrap, push, dock north")" but it just shrinks it down to say 300px in height but retains the proper width

Comment: I'm not 100% sure how you want the jlist to behave, but is it possible that removing this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(800, 600)); solves your problem?

Comment: Hm how would i change the gap between left and list. Not that i would dock the list to JPanel left but just reduce the padding to say 3-5px

Comment: I've tried but haven't gotten anything. Maybe you'll figure it out of you look over the quick start guide (http://www.miglayout.com/QuickStart.pdf) or maybe look for something that'll put you on the right track from their same program (http://www.migcalendar.com/miglayout/swtdemoapp.jnlp).

Answer (score 0):

Use something like

```
new MigLayout("", "0[]0[]0[]0", "[]"); 
this.add(left, "gapx 0 0"); 
this.add(center, "gapx 0 0");
```

Answer (score 0):

I also found it today and setting the insets in the layout constraint solves it.

```
panel.setLayout(new MigLayout("insets 0 0 0 0, fill, debug", "", ""));
```

If we don't set it to `0`, the default size will be set and is huge, like what you saw in your project.